Mineflayer JS | Как я могу получить меню, если его не выдаёт
Есть бот, который заходит, логинится и прочее. Но есть одна проблема: когда срабатывает событие windowOpen, бот не может получить слоты этого меню. Вот что он мне возвращает по команде window.items():
[
  Item {
    type: 648,
    count: 1,
    metadata: 0,
    nbt: null,
    stackId: null,
    name: 'cooked_porkchop',
    displayName: 'Cooked Porkchop',
    stackSize: 64,
    maxDurability: undefined,
    slot: 72
  },
  Item {
    type: 750,
    count: 1,
    metadata: 0,
    nbt: null,
    stackId: null,
    name: 'glass_bottle',
    displayName: 'Glass Bottle',
    stackSize: 64,
    maxDurability: undefined,
    slot: 73
  }
]

Меню выглядит так:


Вместо использования window.items() вы можете использовать window.slots, после этого вы можете получить информацию по любому слоту в меню.
